# Grid splitter not working as expected WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, splitter

Here is my sample code. Tried running it but it is not working as expected.
Refer [Image][1] & [Image][2]

Image 1:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkDhl.png
Image 2: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySUHS.png

According to image 2: Column 2 is not resizing itself on toggle click
Please can someone help on this
Thanks in advance.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Green">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                      Width="30"
                      Height="30"
                      Margin="0,10,10,0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      IsChecked="True" />
    </Border>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <WrapPanel Background="Aqua">
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Item 01" />
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Item 02" />
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Item 03" />
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Item 04" />
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Item 05" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Width="5"
                  ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="3"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Column 2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: CurrentAndNext should be PreviousAndNext

Answer (score 0):

You missed the Grid.ColumnDefinitions.
You'll have to define the corresponding column as `Width="Auto"`.

The BooleanToVisibilityConverter only hides when IsChecked = false which means that the space remains. Write your own BooleanToVisibilityConverter to set Visibility.Collapsed when the incoming bool is false.